# If interface have two methods with same name while implementing which one call first?

Tags: java

code as follows:

```java
interface A
{
 void test();
}

interface B
{
 void test();
}

public class C implements A,B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c=new C(); 
        c.test();
    }
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("hai");
    }
}
```

Here o/p is came, but which interface method was invoked?

Comment: This code is invalid. You can call `new C()`, but you can't instantiate an `A`.

Comment: Your code is not valid! as you cannot instantiate an A

Comment: Sorry now I changed see once again

Answer (score 3):

All that the interfaces require is for you to have a `void` method called `test()`, which takes no arguments.  The implementation of `test()` is in your class, not interface.

Additionally, you cannot instantiate an interface with `new`; however, you could do the following:

```
A a = new C();
```

or

```
B b = new C();
```

**EDIT**:
 It doesn't work if you take the `public` out of your method header, since interface methods **must** be `public`.  Despite you not putting `public` in the interface when declaring the header, interface methods are by default `public`--this cannot be changed, and putting `public` in the header inside of the interface is unnecessary.

Comment: Specifically, a no-argument, no-return-value method called `test`.

Comment: How can I check is my method calling from Interface or class, Is it possible?

Comment: @Prabha All the interface does is declare a contract with the implementing class that mandates that the class have all of the methods in the interface.  So the method is always being called from the implementing class.  If you're trying to determine if the variable is of the interface or the class, you can use `instanceof` to see if its the implement class or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks invalid as you cannot instantiate an A.

You can use `new C()` but at present what you are doing is

```
A a=new A();
```

which is invalid.

So you can probably do like

```
A a = new C();
```

or

```
B b = new C();
```

but you cannot instantiate an interface

**EDIT:-**

After the edit which you have made in your question, it looks like that the implementation of `test()` is in your class, not interface.

Comment: @Prabha:- Now it looks better and you can yourself check that implementation of `test()` function is in your class, not interface.

Comment: so here our class don't call the interface method right? but if i remove public in my class method it will showing compilation error..

Comment: If I remove public specifier in my method it will leading to compilation error. By your discussion if My method in class then why it showing error

Comment: @Prabha Again, see my edit.  I explain why that doesn't work.

Comment: @Prabha:- You have to make the interface methods as public to make it work for you

Comment: Then my method is now class level method or interface method?

Comment: @Prabha:- Your method test is a class level method!

Comment: Thank very much. If I want to implement Interface level method is it possible?

Comment: @Prabha:- You are welcome. You may refer this and it would answer all your queries for interface:- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html

Comment: @Prabha:- And if my answer helped you then you can accept this as answer or give an upvote :)

Comment: How can I check is my method calling from Interface or class, Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cant initiate a interface like you are doing

```
A a=new A();
```

You can do like

```
A a = new C();
```

then there will be no problem which interface method was invoked..